# Rails API: Creating turns into updating when nested attributes have an ID set. Any way to avoid this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I'm slowly moving a legacy FileMaker application to Rails 4.1. To do that I'm in the process of creating a simple Rails JSON API to keep the FileMaker application (which is still being used) and Rails data in sync.

To simplify things I'd like to make use of nested JSON resources where possible - e.g. Creating / updating a contact should automatically include its addresses and other data from related tables. Otherwise I'd have to jump to related records in FileMaker and initialize separate API requests, which is a rather slow process in FileMaker. Handling this in one request is prefered.

Of course it's important to keep the IDs of those existing FileMaker records, which is why they have to be set in those API requests. However it turns out that nested resources in JSON requests that have an ID set automatically trigger an update action for those nested models. Let's look at an example like this small piece of JSON:

```
{
    "id": 7777
    "name": "John Doe"
    "addresses": [
    {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "John Doe",
        "address": "Some Street 12"
        "city": "Sampletown"
        ...
    }, {
        "id": 654,
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "address": "Some other address"
        "city": "Maybe in another city"
        ...
    }]
}
```

If I wanted to push this contact and its addresses from FileMaker to Rails via API request Rails will look for existing addresses with the IDs of 123 and 654 instead of creating new ones with those IDs.

I know this intended by Rails and if I wanted those addresses to be created I'd have to post them without IDs, but as mentioned before it's important to keep the IDs since they are used for all kinds of relations within the application (like order billing and delivery addresses). This behaviour also only seems to apply to nested data. The parent object can be created just fine with any ID.

Of course I could just post addresses as first level (parent) objects in several requests but that would require a lot of jumping around in FileMaker, so if anyone is aware of a way to avoid the default Rails behaviour when it comes to post requests and nested attributes with a fixed ID, I'd be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not considered good style to put any extra meaning into the ID number of a record. The ID number is used for some magic things inside ActiveRecord (as you have experienced) and really should only be used for references into your own system. If you find you need to request a specific ID number for a new record, chances are you are doing it wrong. There are other issues as well, what do you do when IDs collide between Filemaker and Rails, etc.

One alternative would be to use another column specifically for holding a reference into Filemaker. Then if you wanted to you could define a "concern" for all models that carry 
Filemaker reference which handles the abstraction cleanly.

Comment: Well, I didn't have a special meaning in mind - I just thought it would be convenient to use the same IDs that have already been used in the previous system thereby keeping the relations. Turns out it might be more of a problem than a benefit.  

Using something like a fmid column as reference to the IDs used in FileMaker is actually an alternative idea I consider. Seems this is the way to go then.